# Postgres SPI cursor options: Where is a complete list? / What are the default options?

Tags: postgresql

From the Postgresql documentation:

```
int cursorOptions
    Integer bit mask of cursor options; zero produces default behavior.
```

What is the default behavior? Where is a complete list of cursor options? I've been looking through the documentation for an hour now. Can someone provide a link or point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am compiling a list of `cursorOptions` as I peel through the documentation to help save the others the trouble.

Defined in `<src/include/nodes/parsenodes.h>`:

`CURSOR_OPT_BINARY` (0x0001)

`CURSOR_OPT_SCROLL` (0x0002) is required by several SPI commands. Setting this option will allow for more complex movement through cursors. Further details are explained in the documentation of [`SPI_cursor_fetch`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/spi-spi-cursor-fetch.html), [`SPI_cursor_move`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/spi-spi-cursor-move.html), [`SPI_scroll_cursor_fetch`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/spi-spi-scroll-cursor-fetch.html), [`SPI_scroll_cursor_move`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/spi-spi-scroll-cursor-move.html)

`CURSOR_OPT_NO_SCROLL` (0x0004)

`CURSOR_OPT_INSENSITIVE` (0x0008)

`CURSOR_OPT_HOLD` (0x0010) is ignored by [`SPI_prepare_cursor`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/spi-spi-prepare-cursor.html). However, it's behavior for [`SPI_prepare_params`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/spi-spi-prepare-params.html) and [`SPI_cursor_open_with_args`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/spi-spi-cursor-open-with-args.html) is not specified in the documentation.

`CURSOR_OPT_CUSTOM_PLAN` (0x0020)

`CURSOR_OPT_FAST_PLAN` (0x0040)

`CURSOR_OPT_GENERIC_PLAN` (0x0080)

NOTE: If anyone with the ability to edit posts wishes to contribute to this answer (additional options, functionality or insights), please feel free to do so. I will try to move comments up into the answer as they come.

Comment: I'm not checking code, so this might be wrong, but the postgresql 9.1 documentation for SPI_prepare_cursor specifically says CURSOR_OPT_HOLD is ignored.